# Mockito: How do unit test void method java mockito?

Tags: java, mockito, junit5

I have following code I want to unit test:

```
public class TransformarExcel
{

public TransformarExcel() {
    //Constructor
}
  public void validarEntero(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Integer rowCount, String column, String value)
  {
    if (value.equals("0")) {
      generateErrorProcessingFile(request, response, ALERTDANGER, MSGCOLUMNA + column + MSGREGISTRO + rowCount + " no puede ser vacío.");
    }
  }

  public void generateErrorProcessingFile(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, String typeError, String messageError)
  {
      request.setAttribute("typeMessage", typeError);
      request.setAttribute("message", messageError);
      try {
          request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(request, response);
      } catch (ServletException|IOException ex) {
          Logger.getLogger(ServletTransformarExcelDesembolso.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
      }
  }
```

I need to verify that method validarEntero or the method generateErrorProcessingFile are execute, Since both methods do not return anything.

This is I do:

```
@Test
final void testValidarEntero() throws IOException {

        ServletTransformarExcelDesembolso manager = Mockito.mock(ServletTransformarExcelDesembolso.class);
        ServletTransformarExcelDesembolso dato = new ServletTransformarExcelDesembolso(); 
        dato.validarEntero(null, null, null, null, "0");
        verify(manager, Mockito.timeout(1)).validarEntero(null, null, null, null, "0");}
```

Thank you :).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mock` or `spy` objects to verify expected behaviour.

```
@Test
final void testValidarEntero() throws IOException {

    HttpServletRequest mockRequest = Mockito.mock(HttpServletRequest.class);
    Mockito.when(mockRequest.getRequestDispatcher(anyString())).thenReturn(Mockito.mock(RequestDispatcher.class));

    ServletTransformarExcelDesembolso dato = new ServletTransformarExcelDesembolso(); 
    dato.validarEntero(mockRequest, null, null, null, "0");

    verify(mockRequest, Mockito.times(1)).getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp");
}
```

Comment: When I do so, I get the following error: java.lang.NullPointerExceptionat co.com.ias.bancolombia.transformarexcel.ServletTransformarExcelDesembolso.generateErrorProcessingFile(ServletTransformarExcelDesembolso.java:356)
 at co.com.ias.bancolombia.transformarexcel.ServletTransformarExcelDesembolso.validarEntero(ServletTransformarExcelDesembolso.java:420)
 at test.java.src.ServletTransformarExcelDesembolsoTest.testValidarEntero(ServletTransformarExcelDesembolsoTest.java:159)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at

Comment: Sorry, you also need to add a when on the request mock. Since mockito mocks return null by default. This causes the NPE you see.

Comment: `Mockito.when(mockRequest.getRequestDispatcher(anyString())).thenReturn(mock(RequestDispatcher.class));`